# Detect source color after mixing rgb

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, colors

Trying to detect source color after mixing it with another one.
For example:

```
    color -> (a, r, g, b)
    source -> (255, 128, 64, 64)
    overlay -> (204, 0, 128, 128)
    result -> (255, 26, 115, 115)
```

After mixing source color with overlay (with normal blending mode), i get the result color.
Knowing, that source alpha and result alpha are constants, for calculating result color I use this formula:

```
    result.red = source.red + (overlay.red - source.red) * overlay.alpha / 255;
```

respectively for the rest blue and green channels the same formula.
The first trouble I face, is that the result value is rounded, so instead of 25.6 (for result R), I will get 26 (because rgb are byte values).
So, this will cause the problem while detecting source color, knowing only result and overlay. So, using this formula:

```
    source.red = (255 * result.red - overlay.red * overlay.alpha) / (255 - overlay.alpha)
```

will result source red value = 130 insted of 128 (because result red value is 26 insted of 25.6).
Any ideas how the source color can be calculated another way?

Comment: If you round the number many source values can equal the same output value. Therefore the source value is unrecoverable from the output value.